# Anychart Radar Chart Label Font Size

Tags: font-size, anychart, radar-chart

How do I change the font size on the labels on any chart radar chart?

[AnyChart Radar Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqUIl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Text labels are on the X axis:

```js
// adjust x axis
chart
    .xAxis()
    .labels()
    .fontFamily("Iosevka")
    .fontSize(28)
    .fontColor("#000")
    .fontWeight("bold");
```

Numbers are on the Y axis:

```js
// adjust x axis
    chart
        .yAxis()
        .labels()
        .fontFamily("Iosevka")
        .fontSize(28)
        .fontColor("#000")
        .fontWeight("bold");
```